# Program will not run because of error code * Program does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point

Tags: c#

```
class CollegeStudent
{
    // fields
    private string studentName;
    private int midTerm1;
    private int midTerm2;
    private int finalExam;
    // properties
    public string StudentId
    {
        get { return studentName; }
        set { studentName = value; }
    }
    public int MidTerm1
    {
        get { return midTerm1; }
        set { midTerm1 = value; }
```

I don't know where to enter the entry point and Im pretty much stuck.  I have read another post, but it is not very clear on how they solved it and when I try to apply what they did to my own it does not work.  If anyone can help with this it be great.  The code itself reads * program does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point

Comment: Well what do you want to happen when you run your program? You've got to tell the code where to start - at least if you're writing an *application* rather than a *library*. (As a side-note, I suggest you look into *automatically implemented properties* which will make your code a lot simpler.)

Comment: thats the question to debug code even though your snippet is cut - please consider using visual studio along with auto generated project ( you can start with console app)

Comment: Please provide a code sample of how your running the code along with your expected behavior. Following this guideline will help the community be able to your answer your question better https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

Your project type is console that required main static method it is called (driver method) it is mandatory to run console application .

```
static void Main(string[] args)  
{  
//...  
}
```

If you want to make DLL , you should use Class Library Project type [add class library in visual studio 2017](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/61b832/creating-class-library-in-visual-C-Sharp/).